# differential equation by maxima

Tags: differential-equations, maxima

I am new in maxima, so I am really sorry if I ask simple question. I have a differential equation,

```
(%i1) -(x-x/2*sinh(x/2)+'diff(y,x))*(1/y+'diff(y,x)*x/y^2)+(x-x^2/sinh(x/2)+x^2*cosh(x/2)/(4*(sinh(x/2))^2)+'diff(y,x)*x+'diff(y,x,2)*x^2)/y+y^2-1-0.9*(x-x^2/(2*sinh(x/2)))=0;
                             2      x
      2              2      x  cosh(-)
   2 d y     dy     x               2
  x  --- + x -- - ------- + ---------- + x
       2     dx        x          2 x
     dx           sinh(-)   4 sinh (-)
                       2            2
(%o1) ----------------------------------------
                     y
                      x          dy
               x sinh(-)       x --                          2
          dy          2          dx   1     2               x
     + (- -- + --------- - x) (---- + -) + y  - 0.9 (x - ---------) - 1 = 0
          dx       2             2    y                         x
                                y                        2 sinh(-)
                                                                2
```

[image: y' is the differentiation of y respect to x]

```
(%i2) ode2(%,y,x);
rat: replaced -0.9 by -9/10 = -0.9
(%o2)                                false
```

what should I do?

Comment: Can't tell what's wrong.  I'd recommend adding more explanation and using LaTeX to render your math in a more readable form.

Answer (score 2):

The equation you have is nonlinear. Maxima's `ode2` can only solve a limited variety of differential equations, and it appears your equation doesn't fall into any of the categories it can handle.

I don't know if there is another symbolic diff eq solver in Maxima that you can try. If a numerical solution is enough, take a look at `rk` (a Runge-Kutta implementation).